# SQL 'Like' operator and 'aa'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, internationalization

We've stumbled upon a very odd problem in one of our applications. The seach engine uses a stored procedure to compare a bunch of filters. However when a specific type of string is inserted, the sql server (2005) behaves very odd. I've isolated the problem to the following:

```
select 'match!' where  'teliaa' like '%telia%'
```

The collation is Danish Norwegian CI AS and we have characters that mean the same thing. This includes 'aa' which also means 'å'.

Can anyone explain why the above statement does not yield 'match!'

Comment: You haven't said what the 'odd' behaviour actually is.

Comment: Don't keep us in suspense... what does the query return?

Comment: select 'match!' where  'teliaardvark' like '%telia%' - will also match.  The closing % is a wildcard.

Comment: Oh, I guess I wasn't precise enough. The odd behavior is that the sql statement is not a match.

Answer (score 3):

The collation won't automatically match "aa" to "å".

It will make sure that "å" is sorted correctly and some other stuff but *it won't substitute*.
<strike>The same applies "ss" vs "ß" in German, for example</strike>

You'd have to clean the data one way or the other.

```
SELECT REPLACE ('teliå', 'å', 'aa'), /* ...or  */REPLACE ('teliaa', 'aa', 'å')
```

Edit, May 2013

I'm guessing `å` does not match `aa` in that collation.
However it does sort correctly

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE (bar varchar(2))
INSERT @foo VALUES ('Ab'),('Aa'),('aa'), ('å'), ('Za');

SELECT * FROM @foo ORDER BY bar COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS;

SELECT * FROM @foo WHERE bar COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS = 'Aa';
SELECT * FROM @foo WHERE bar COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS = 'a';
SELECT * FROM @foo WHERE bar COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS = 'å';
```

Comment: We do normalize both the filter parameters and the data in the database before comparing. However the above state does not match (neither does Meep3D's example). The question is why the string 'teliaa' is not matched up with '%telia%' .

Answer (score 1):

Collation is the collection of rules for comparing characters, most useful for sorting. Some say it only affects sorting, this is not entirely correct. From https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

> A SQL Server collation defines how the database engine stores and operates on character and Unicode data.

As an example, in the Danish_Norwegian accent insensitive collations matches 'aa' with 'å'. Names that begin with 'aa' are sorted alongside names that begin with 'å'. However, it also affects comparisons and the LIKE operator. Here are some query strings illustrating this.

```
select 'match!' where  'teliaa' collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AI like '%telia%' --yields "match!"
select 'match!' where  'teliaa' collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AS like '%telia%' --yields "match!"
select 'match!' where  'teliaa' collate Latin1_General_100_CS_AI like '%telia%' --yields "match!"
select 'match!' where  'teliaa' collate Latin1_General_100_CS_AS like '%telia%' --yields "match!"

select 'match!' where  'teliaa' collate Danish_Norwegian_CI_AI like '%telia%' --no rows
select 'match!' where  'teliaa' collate Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS like '%telia%' --no rows
select 'match!' where  'teliaa' collate Danish_Norwegian_CS_AI like '%telia%' --no rows
select 'match!' where  'teliaa' collate Danish_Norwegian_CS_AS like '%telia%' --no rows

select 'match!' where  'teliaa' collate Danish_Norwegian_CI_AI like '%å%' --yields "match!"
select 'match!' where  'teliaa' collate Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS like '%å%' --no rows
select 'match!' where  'teliaa' collate Danish_Norwegian_CS_AI like '%å%' --yields "match!"
select 'match!' where  'teliaa' collate Danish_Norwegian_CS_AS like '%å%' --no rows
```

Depending on your need, if you need to match 'aa' to 'å', treating them the same, then select a collation that supports this in your query or data store/columns. If not, then select a collation like Latin1_General_100_CI_AI.

Answer (score -2):

```
select 'match!' where  'teliaa' like '%telia%'
```

gives 'match!' as output on my sql-2008 (SP1)10.0.2531.0(x64)

i can't answer your question...

Comment: Why the downvote? My answer to the result of the select statement is correct as also stated with the check.

Comment: I guess the downvote is because you have factored in the collation

Comment: And it does not answer the question as you said but it still gets accepted

Comment: The result of select 'match!' where  'teliaa' like '%telia%' is 'match!' . What factored collation should there be? Please explain such vague speech. At the time of my answer,there was no explicit question - what is the problem?

Comment: select 'match!' where  'teliaa' like '%teliå%' gives no match that's for shure! because the collation is standard Latin1_General_CI_AS: Case Insensitive and Accent senstive.

Comment: select 'match!' where  'teliaa' like '%teliå%' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI
This one gives the desired match! because accent insensitive is set by the collate option!
So the answer to the initial Question is: set a collation with 'AI'.