# SQL LIKE with special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I try to create a select with special (nordic) characters like:

```
Select * from users where name like '%æ%'
```

It just selects all users instead of those containing the letter 'æ'.

Do I need to install some special drivers to the database, or is there something else I have missed?

Update:
I am using a SQL Server 2008 database, the collation is set to 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' and the datafield is a nullable nVarChar datatype.

Comment: What kind of SQL you're using?

Comment: What datatype is name please? What collation too?

Comment: Sorry it should now be updated with the needed information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely some collation or datatype issue

Example, gives 97 and 230

```
SELECT ASCII('æ' COLLATE Albanian_CI_AI), ASCII('æ' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)
```

We'll need more info basically.

Edit: [Question about Danish/Norwegian å](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171510) (although unresolved)

Edit 2: change the code to this if name is nvarchar so the literal becomes unicode too.

```
Select * from users where name like N'%æ%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using an extended character set (UTF-8) and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

it should be work correctly ..
but try this `Select * from users where name like '%[æ]%'`

Comment: It works, but I can't manually escape the variables, since it is a search input.

Comment: I use NHibernate which uses parameters for search input, so it should be working against sql injection.