# SQL Server GUID sometimes valid and sometimes not

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I'm having a problem with a GUID which I've narrowed down to what looks like a problem with the `LIKE` operator.

When the following is run on my server

```
DECLARE @Problem NVARCHAR(1000) = N'58C21BC6-081B-4E57-BFE1-5B11AAC662F1';

DECLARE @GuidPattern NVARCHAR(1000) = 
    REPLICATE('[0-9A-Fa-f]', 8)
    + '-'
    + REPLICATE('[0-9A-Fa-f]', 4)
    + '-'
    + REPLICATE('[0-9A-Fa-f]', 4)
    + '-'
    + REPLICATE('[0-9A-Fa-f]', 4)
    + '-'
    + REPLICATE('[0-9A-Fa-f]', 12);

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN @Problem LIKE @GuidPattern THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS [FollowsPattern];
```

the answer is `0`, but when I run the exact same code on my local machine the answer is `1`.

It looks pretty obvious to me that the string is in fact a valid GUID, so the answer should be `1` in both cases. All the other ways I know about to confirm that the GUID is valid also succeed, both locally and on the server:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN CAST(@Problem AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) = @Problem THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS [IsGuid1]; -- 1

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @Problem) = @Problem THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS [IsGuid2]; -- 1

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @Problem) IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS [IsGuid3]; -- 1
```

The server version is

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64) 
    Apr 29 2016 23:23:58 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

and my local installation version is

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64)
    Feb 20 2014 20:04:26
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

The default collation is the not the same (`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` locally and `Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS` on the server), but I don't think that should matter since I'm dealing with Unicode anyway. <s>Adding an extra `COLLATE` clause on either machine with the other's collation makes no difference.</s> **Update:** Not true, the collation is the source of the problem. I only tested different collations in the variable declaration, not in the comparison itself.

Comment: a reduced version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9577359/3270427

Comment: The GUID is provided by an integration that I have no control over and is used to correlate the row across multiple tables. Everything indicates that the integration does use the equivalent of `NEWID`, but I used a string constant here since I was able to track down one particular GUID instance that caused the problem (the vast majority we receive do not). Still, that doesn't explain the problem.

Comment: rextester.com returns 1

Comment: @McNets The reduced version gives the same result (i.e. empty result set on the server and `1` locally).

Comment: Sorry for my first comment, got it wrong completely... Just if I understand that correctly: Your question is: *How does it come, that the first code returns 1 on my local installation while the same code returns 0 on your server?* The question is not: *How can I prove if a string is a valid GUID?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the problem is COLLATION.

Have a look at: http://rextester.com/IRQEFU33639

If you use default collation:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN @Problem LIKE @GuidPattern THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS [FollowsPattern];
```

The result = 1

Instead, if you forces Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS collation:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN @Problem collate Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS  LIKE @GuidPattern THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS [FollowsPattern];
```

It returns 0.

I'd suggest to force the collation to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS or other collation that works well.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN @Problem COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS LIKE @GuidPattern THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS [FollowsPattern];
```

And just to make it easy maybe using an [INLINE User Defined Function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: I checked this, and it seems to be true, that the collation is the reason for this. I must admit, that I did not expect this...

Comment: I suppose it is related to the regex expression, maybe for Norwegian language you need to change it.

Comment: Demo in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171510/sql-like-operator-and-aa

Comment: Yep, you must deal with it. I'd suggest a inline udf just to make it shorter.

Comment: This solves the issue. `AA` is collated as `Å` after `Z` in Danish and Norwegian (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85).

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Force to a standard collation

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN @Problem COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS LIKE @GuidPattern COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS [FollowsPattern];
```

The reason is how "a" is matched in `Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS` collation.

See [SQL 'Like' operator and 'aa'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171510/sql-like-operator-and-aa) for more where I demonstrated it with Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS

Comment: Yes, that would probably be the best solution. I originally encountered this when looking up a GUID in a column of GUIDs-as-strings in an SSIS job - a somewhat different scenario than what I described in the question - so I'll have to adapt this to the real issue somehow.