# Case sensitive record in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I use SQL Server 2012. The database collation is 'CI' (Case Insensitive). When selecting from aspnet_users, the usernames is case insensitive as espected. But, some single records in the table still seems to be case sensitive, and I don't understand why.

Expample: I have a record with the username "MariaA".

This select statement returns the record correct:

```
SELECT [UserName] FROM [aspnet_Users] where UserName = 'MariaA'
```

This select statement also returns the record correct:

```
SELECT [UserName] FROM [aspnet_Users] where UserName = 'mariaA'
```

if I run this statement, the user is NOT returned:

```
SELECT [UserName] FROM [aspnet_Users] where UserName = 'Mariaa'
```

if I run this statement, the user is NOT returned:

```
SELECT [UserName] FROM [aspnet_Users] where UserName = 'mariaa'
```

Question: It seems like the upper case character 'A' is case sensitive. All other characters can be case insensitive. This problem also occur with other userprofiles, when the username contains the uppercase 'A' it cannot be written in lowercase 'a'.

Why is this happening, and how can it be solved?

Comment: share sample data

Comment: Is the `A` really a capital a, or a character that *looks* like a capital a?

Comment: What is the exact type and collation of `UserName` column in the table?

Comment: The username column is 'Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS'

Comment: I believe A really is capital a. But, is there any way to check this for sure?

Comment: You can cast it to a `VARBINARY`, a capital a is `41`.

Comment: I think the problem is that in Danish collation `aa` = `å`, but `aA` <> `å`. Not sure what the solution would be, but I recon this is the cause. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171510/sql-like-operator-and-aa)

Answer (score 1):

use `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` in where clause

```
WITH cte AS
(

    select 'MariaA' as username
) select * from cte where username='mariaA' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

By default it is case insensitive

so the below query will return a row where it will match

```
WITH cte AS
(

    select 'MariaA' as username
) select * from cte where username='MariaA' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Comment: But the column already is `Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS`, which is also case insensitive right?

Comment: In this case, can you try `SELECT * from cte where username='Mariaa' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`? It doesn't return a value.

Comment: Yes, the column is already case insensitive (Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS). That's why I don't understand why it sometimes differs between 'A' and 'a'...

Comment: It does work with `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS`, the reason for this I cannot tell...

Comment: @HoneyBadger check the sqlserver documentation you will get answer even your database case sensative does not mean your column as it is btw hope you will get answer

Comment: @HoneyBadger http://vyaskn.tripod.com/case_sensitive_search_in_sql_server.htm it seems here also noted things in good way

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin No, it don't work. Since the database collation is 'CI' (Case Insensitive) it must be something else that causes this strange behaviour. It should not differ between A and a... I cannot rewrite all SQL procedures in our application to bypass this error.

Comment: I don't want to match the case (COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS), I wan't it to be case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

In Danish collation `aa` is a single character, while `aA` is interpreted as two characters (regardless of case sensitivity of the collation).

If it is practical, you can do the comparison in upper case:

```
WITH cte AS
(

    select 'MariaA' as username 
) 

SELECT * from cte where UPPER(username)=UPPER('Mariaa') COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand why this happens. I will try to keep the correct case in SQL since aa and aA not is the same in Danish_Norwegian collation. It also works using COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS.